# Trying to import a c++ dll to a c-sharp code

Tags: c#, c++, dll, pinvoke, marshalling

I'm trying to make the most simple example, just so that I begin to understand how this is done. Searching the web I only found examples I don't quite understand.

This is the c++ code, in a C++ class library project.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include "ClassLibrary1.h"
using namespace std;

extern "C" { 
    void CallMe()
    {
        cout << "I am the called function! Hooray!" << endl;
    }
}
```

This is the C# Console application code:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("calling dll");
            CallMe();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        [DllImport("ClassLibrary1.dll")]
        public static extern void CallMe();
    }
}
```

I added the dll as a reference to the C# project, and also placed it in the same folder as the executable.

Still I get an "***Unable to load DLL "ClassLibrary1.dll": the specified module could not be found (exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)***".

What am I missing?

I tried adding "__declspec(dllexport)" before the declaration of CallMe in the C++ code, but no luck.

Comment: Either the ClassLibrary1.dll is not copied to the C# project output directory, or you have a platform mismatch, meaning C# run as 64-bit while your DLL is 32-bit (or the other way). It's a loading issue not an export symbol issue and I strongly assume it's the platform mismatch issue.

Comment: Where is your DLL located? Is that location in the `PATH` variable?

Comment: It might be missing VCRedist packages in your installation. Odd if you built everything on the same machine.

Comment: Why did you add it as a reference? It's an unmanaged library surely. Or is it not?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ - you're right, I accidently placed the dll in the wrong folder. But I'm still getting another error, please check the edit

Comment: @MelissaP - actually you were also right, don't know how I missed that one... :-\

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - what do you mean?

Comment: You add managed libraries as references. This is an unmanaged library. Don't add it as a reference. Did you compile the DLL linking to the runtime dynamically or statically?

Comment: @ David Heffernan - oh ok, this one didn't throw an error, but I removed it from the reference.

Comment: Hi David. Please add your answers to an answer box, rather than editing the question. A question can only take so much editing before it becomes an answer without a question, which is probably not very useful for future readers! I have done it for you on this occasion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*(Posted on behalf of the OP)*.

The solutions were, respectively:

> Still I get an "Unable to load DLL "ClassLibrary1.dll": the specified module could not be found (exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)".

Mistake #1: wrong placement of dll, sorry.

> Now I get a new error: "An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007000B)"

Mistake #2: c++ code was compiled as x86, instead of x64, double sorry.

> I now get the error: "Unable to find entery point named "CallMe" in dll"

Mistake #3: you must put "__declspec(dllexport)" when declaring/defining the function.